# Structure size so big, need optimization

Tags: c++, c, gcc, struct, packet

i have a big problems with my code for one function i code this for one game, to send packets from server to client, all works good but problem is in server so big size.. with more small size like 100-300 works good, but i have problem in my source because they have a protection to check buffers from packets and if to great will block to send function, so i need other function i think or much optimization or other structure.. hmm

Here is problem - TPacket list[1000];

```
typedef struct testa
{
    char    t_A[10 + 1];
    char    t_B[12 + 1];
    char    t_C[32 + 1];
    char    t_D[512 + 1];
    int     t_E;
    char    t_F[19 + 1];
    int     t_G;
} TPacket;

typedef struct testb
{
    BYTE header;
    TPacket list[1000]; // (If i put example 200 etc work) but when is so big = buffer mem_size overflow. memsize(131072) write_pos(32) iSize(598001)
} Test;

// FUNCTION TO SEND:
    Test p;
    p.header = HEADER_GC_T;

    SQLMsg *pMsg = DBManager::instance().DirectQuery("SELECT * FROM table.list ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1000");
    MYSQL_ROW row;
    int i = 0;

    if(pMsg->uiSQLErrno != 0)
        return;

    while ((row = mysql_fetch_row(pMsg->Get()->pSQLResult)))
    {
        p.list[i] = TPacket();
        strncpy(p.list[i].t_A, row[1], sizeof(p.list[i].t_A));
        strncpy(p.list[i].t_B, row[2], sizeof(p.list[i].t_B));
        strncpy(p.list[i].t_C, row[3], sizeof(p.list[i].t_C));
        strncpy(p.list[i].t_D, row[4], sizeof(p.list[i].t_D));
        str_to_number(p.list[i].t_E, row[5]);
        strncpy(p.list[i].t_F, row[6], sizeof(p.list[i].t_F) - 1);
        str_to_number(p.list[i].t_G, row[7]);
        i++;
    }

    if(pMsg->Get()->uiNumRows < 1000)
    {
        while (i < 1000)
        {
            p.list[i] = TPacket();
            strncpy(p.list[i].t_A, "", sizeof(p.list[i].t_A));
            strncpy(p.list[i].t_B, "", sizeof(p.list[i].t_B));
            strncpy(p.list[i].t_C, "", sizeof(p.list[i].t_C));
            strncpy(p.list[i].t_D, "", sizeof(p.list[i].t_D));          
            p.list[i].t_E = 0;          
            strncpy(p.list[i].t_F, "", sizeof(p.list[i].t_F) - 1);          
            p.list[i].t_G = 0;              
            i++;
        }
    }
    ch->GetDesc()->Packet(&p, sizeof(p));
```

Comment: It sounds like the real problem is that you need to use non-blocking sends.

Comment: Are you using C or C++?  If C++ I would suggest `std::string` for the cstring and `std::vector` to replace the other arrays.

Comment: That's to big for your stack. Replace `TPacket list[1000];` with `std::vector<TPacket> list(1000);`

Comment: As @πάνταῥεῖ says, you're hitting the stack frame size limit. You could do it using a global variable or dynamic allocation.

Comment: "they have a protection to check buffers from packets" -- Who is "they" and what packets are you talking about here?

Comment: Don't use `char` for packet values, because `char` type is either `signed char`, `unsigned char` or `char`.  Always use unsigned type when transmitting binary data, such as `uint8_t`.

Comment: Be aware that compilers are allowed to add *padding* between structure members.

Comment: DONT USE `strncpy`: https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2013/04/03/stop-using-strncpy-already/

Answer (score 1):

Your `Test` structure is quite large, 588,000 bytes, which might be too large for automatic storage.  Make it `static` should solve the problem, but will make your code non reentrant and definitely not thread safe.

If the problem is with the maximum packet size, you must break the transmission into smaller packets. Use a smaller number of items in both the structure and the SQL `SELECT` statement.

`strncpy` does not null terminate the strings if they are longer than the destination arrays. You should NEVER use this function.  Read why you should [stop using strncpy already!](https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2013/04/03/stop-using-strncpy-already/). You can instead use a different function that copies with truncation but does null terminate the destination.

The clearing loop can be drastically simplified, assuming the default constructor for TPacket produces a TPacket initialized to all bits 0. If it does not, just use `memset` to do that.

```
typedef struct testa {
    char t_A[10 + 1];
    char t_B[12 + 1];
    char t_C[32 + 1];
    char t_D[512 + 1];
    int  t_E;
    char t_F[19 + 1];
    int  t_G;
} TPacket;

typedef struct testb {
    BYTE header;
    TPacket list[200];
} Test;

// Utility function: copy with truncation, return source string length
// truncation occurred if return value >= size argument
size_t bstrcpy(char *dest, size_t size, const char *src) {
    size_t i;
    /* copy the portion that fits */
    for (i = 0; i + 1 < size && src[i] != '\0'; i++) {
         dest[i] = src[i];
    }
    /* null terminate destination if possible */
    if (i < size) {
        dest[i] = '\0';
    }
    /* compute necessary length to allow truncation detection */
    while (src[i] != '\0') {
        i++;
    }
    return i;
}

// FUNCTION TO SEND:
void myfunction() {
    Test p;
    p.header = HEADER_GC_T;

    SQLMsg *pMsg = DBManager::instance().DirectQuery("SELECT * FROM table.list ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 200");
    MYSQL_ROW row;
    int i = 0;

    if (pMsg->uiSQLErrno != 0)
        return;

    while ((row = mysql_fetch_row(pMsg->Get()->pSQLResult))) {
        p.list[i] = TPacket();
        bstrcpy(p.list[i].t_A, sizeof(p.list[i].t_A), row[1]);
        bstrcpy(p.list[i].t_B, sizeof(p.list[i].t_B), row[2]);
        bstrcpy(p.list[i].t_C, sizeof(p.list[i].t_C), row[3]);
        bstrcpy(p.list[i].t_D, sizeof(p.list[i].t_D), row[4]);
        str_to_number(p.list[i].t_E, row[5]);
        bstrcpy(p.list[i].t_F, sizeof(p.list[i].t_F), row[6]);
        str_to_number(p.list[i].t_G, row[7]);
        i++;
    }

    if (i < 1000) {
        memset(&p.list[i], 0, (1000 - i) * sizeof(p.list[i]));
        //while (i < 1000) {
        //    p.list[i] = TPacket();
        //    i++;
        //}
    }
    ch->GetDesc()->Packet(&p, sizeof(p));
```

Comment: @Dr.Vendetta: why do you no longer consider this answer acceptable?